# Непонятная ошибка mongodb

Tags: javascript, база-данных, node.js, mongodb

При втором post запросе на сайт вылетает ошибка, я не понимаю в чем проблема

> (node:10188) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Topology is closed, please connect
> at processWaitQueue

Это часть основного файл с подключенным express

```
const client = require('./database')

app.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  try {
    await client.connect()
    const database = client.db('app')
    const collection = database.collection('list')
    const doc = { name: 'Red', town: 'kanto' }
    const result = await collection.insert(doc)
    console.log(
      `${result.insertedCount} documents were inserted with the _id: ${result.insertedId}`
    )
  } finally {
    await client.close()
  }
  res.render('create')
})
```

Файл database.js

```
const config = require('./config')
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')

const client = new MongoClient(config.MONGODB_URI, { useUnifiedTopology: true })

module.exports = client
```

Comment: а если убрать `await client.close()`, то заработает?

Comment: Да, все работает

Comment: если честно, то я уже не помню как правильно здесь поступить)) давно с *mongoDB* и его *ODM* не работал. ожидайте более опытного специалиста)